# jquery emoticon click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one question about jquery `click` function. I have created this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/dn2pk4sg/2/) on jsfiddle.

In this demo you can see, there are three `textarea` and **smileys**. When you click on one smiley, then something is going wrong, because the **smiley** `sticker="(w1)"` is being added in all three `textarea`s.

How can I fix this problem?
 Anyone can help me in this regard ?

HTML:

```
<div class="container one">
<textarea class="add-y-comment" name="comment" id="ctextarea453" data-id="453" placeholder="First Text area"></textarea>

<div class="stiemo"><img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140214223249/clubpenguin/images/e/e1/CPNext_Emoticon_-_Winking_Face.png" class="sm-sticker" sticker="(w1)"> click for first textarea</div>
</div>



<div class="container two">
<textarea class="add-y-comment" name="comment" id="ctextarea453" data-id="453" placeholder="Second Text area"></textarea>

<div class="stiemo"><img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140214223249/clubpenguin/images/e/e1/CPNext_Emoticon_-_Winking_Face.png" class="sm-sticker" sticker="(w1)"> click for second textarea</div>
</div>



<div class="container tree">
<textarea class="add-y-comment" name="comment" id="ctextarea453" data-id="453"  placeholder="Third Text area"></textarea>

<div class="stiemo"><img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140214223249/clubpenguin/images/e/e1/CPNext_Emoticon_-_Winking_Face.png" class="sm-sticker" sticker="(w1)"> click for third textarea</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('click', '.sm-sticker', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var sticker = $(this).attr('sticker');
        var msg = jQuery.trim($('.add-y-comment').val());

        if(msg == ''){
           var sp = '';
        } else {
           var sp = ' ';
        }
        $('.add-y-comment').val(jQuery.trim(msg + sp + sticker + sp));
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made some confusions. You take the value of any field calling `add-y-comment`, but you only want to target the current one with `$(this)`

First, creating a variable because we will use it several times

```
var theComment = $(this).parents('.container').find('.add-y-comment');
```

Then change to this

```
var msg = jQuery.trim(theComment.val());
```

And finally (after your code), add this :

```
theComment.val(jQuery.trim(msg + sp + sticker + sp));
```

Complete code :

```
$('body').on('click', '.sm-sticker', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var theComment = $(this).parents('.container').find('.add-y-comment');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var sticker = $(this).attr('sticker');
    var msg = jQuery.trim(theComment.val());

    if(msg == ''){
        var sp = '';
    } else {
        var sp = ' ';
    }

    theComment.val(jQuery.trim(msg + sp + sticker + sp));
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zlen/uysoh6gb/) updated

Answer (score 0):

Its just because of your two lines of snippet -

```
var msg = jQuery.trim($('.add-y-comment').val());
.
.
.
$('.add-y-comment').val(jQuery.trim(msg + sp + sticker + sp));
```

In both of these lines you don't retrieve and update the value of the `textarea` which is present just before the emoticon which is clicked. Here is the correct code for it -

```
var msg = jQuery.trim($(this).parent('.stiemo').prev('.add-y-comment').val());
.
.
.
$(this).parent('.stiemo').prev('.add-y-comment').val(jQuery.trim(msg + sp + sticker + sp));
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dn2pk4sg/4/)